# How can I detect the requesting client is a browser or page is being requested via HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, server, httpwebrequest

Okay, it would be a very general question, I won't share any source code because It needs a theoretical explanation.

I am loading a web page in my browser be it `chrome` or `firefox` and the page is loading fine. the thing that is not working and made me curious is, When I get the source of that specific page using `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient` or any library such as `RestSharp`, My Requests to that page got blocked and instead of getting the actual `HTML` I get back an error page.

So, I wanted to ask what is this happening? When I load it in browser it works fine, but when I switch back to the `HttpClient` it gets blocked(At least that is what I think). Please share your experiences and also let me know how can I do this in my Web Applications to detect from where the request is coming? Any help would be appreciated.

PS: It even fails on `Postman`.

Here is the error:

> The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your
> administrator.

Comment: Web Server can decide which request must be rejected or not. Maybe it depends on `User-Agent` string or something else. Looks like a protection against bots. You may look at the Browser Network log and see what happens there. Both Chrome and Firefox have Developer Tools. Then you may try to emulate the browser's behavior.

Comment: I have tried different user agent strings but it returns the same result, I am not consuming any API, I am requesting a web page and getting the html of that page.

Comment: Theory will not help there. Looks like you're doing in a right way. Need practical request+response Headers inspection with comparison to Browser.

Comment: Browser is not sending any parameters, as it is a get request to the page. I don't if I am doing it right, but that is a clear thing that they are detecting my request through postman/webrequest and blocking it.

Comment: If you have answer to the question in the title you can sell it for huge amounts of money...  Unfortunately there is absolutely no way to distinguish *identical* requests made by browser or any other software... (Note that what you actually after is opposite - "why request I'm making by hand is different from one by browser" - and there is no way to answer it without seeing both... but at that point you'd better be able to do diff yourself. I'd strongly recommend something like Fiddler to capture both and do diff)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov exactly, or WireShark to capture the TCP packets and inspect as HTTP.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I am using firefox extension `Http Header Live` This gives me very basic headers that are passed such as Host, User-Agent, Accept, Connection etc. I would have distinguished between both requests what to pass. But it somehow, detects from where it is coming.

Comment: @Jamshaid Your problem is probably not setting the request headers properly as same with browser and ServicePoint settings. Share the url please